# Comparing properties of an html class with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, class

There's so many questions similar to mine that I get a flood of wrong questions and I can't seem to tell if mine is a duplicate or not. 
I signed up for an account to ask this.

My problem is that the code is giving me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token"

**HTML**

```
<section class="shopBoxBot" href="index.html">
<img class="shopImg" src=Images/Shop/Amethyst_Bracelet.jpg>
<p> hi </p>
</section>
```

**Javascript**

```
var shopSizer = document.querySelectorAll(".shopImg");
for (var i = 0; i < shopSizer.length; i++){
if (shopSizer[i].width => shopSizer[i].height){
  shopSizer[i].style.height='100%';
}
else{ shopSizer[i].style.width='100%'; 
}
}
```

All I want is to compare and see which is larger, the height or width, and then based on that decide which one to make the size of the parent.

The error occurs on this line

```
if (shopSizer[i].width => shopSizer[i].height){
```

Comment: Please sort out the indentation in the JS

Comment: it should be >= not =<

Comment: Change `=>` to `>=`

Comment: of course it was something silly... thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

You are using the comparision operator wrongly. `=>` should be `>=`

```
if (shopSizer[i].width => shopSizer[i].height){
```

should be

```
if (shopSizer[i].width >= shopSizer[i].height){
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<section class="shopBoxBot" href="index.html">
<img class="shopImg" src=Images/Shop/Amethyst_Bracelet.jpg>
<p> hi </p>
</section>
```

Javascript

```
var shopSizer = document.querySelectorAll(".shopImg");
for (var i = 0; i < shopSizer.length; i++){
if (shopSizer[i].width >= shopSizer[i].height){
shopSizer[i].style.height='100%';
}
else{ shopSizer[i].style.width='100%'; 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error is in the operation "=>" you should write ">="
if (shopSizer[i].width >= shopSizer[i].height)

Answer (score 0):

In line `if (shopSizer[i].width => shopSizer[i].height){`, you are using `=>` which is not a comparision operator. The operaator you want is `>=`

Take a look at this [list of comparison operators](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) in javascript

So, your javascript becomes :

```
var shopSizer = document.querySelectorAll(".shopImg");
for (var i = 0; i < shopSizer.length; i++){
    if (shopSizer[i].width >= shopSizer[i].height){
        shopSizer[i].style.height='100%';
    }
    else{ shopSizer[i].style.width='100%'; 
    }
}
```